# Python - Storing user input and checking if the input has already been entered?

Tags: python

How would I go about allowing users to enter one word at a time then press enter and if the user enters a word they have already entered before, 
the program will tell them they have made a mistake and then continue letting them enter new words?

Answer (score 1):

add the input value to a list

```
alist = []
```

and each time the user inputs something,

```
while True:
    #have user input something

    if "input" in alist:
        #tell user his variable is already stored
    else:
        alist.append(userinput)
```

Comment: You'll have to add this code into a loop, example 
    
    `while True:`

to allow the user to enter multiple words.

Comment: modified example accordingly.